# How to get rid of unattended breakpoints in Python library code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-debugging

Every time I start a debugging process for Python code in Visual Studio 2015, I need to go through a lot of stops at several lines in Python library, which are executed before my code is loaded. For example, there are unattended breakpoints (which are not shown in interface) at line 143, 147 and 184 of `site.py`

```
def addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths):
"""Process a .pth file within the site-packages directory:
   For each line in the file, either combine it with sitedir to a path
   and add that to known_paths, or execute it if it starts with 'import '.
"""
if known_paths is None:
    _init_pathinfo()
    reset = 1
else:
    reset = 0
fullname = os.path.join(sitedir, name)
try:
    f = open(fullname, "rU")  # <-- Line 143
except IOError:
    return
with f:
    for n, line in enumerate(f):  #  <-- Line 147
        if line.startswith("#"):
            continue
        try:
            if line.startswith(("import ", "import\t")):
                exec line
                continue
            line = line.rstrip()
            dir, dircase = makepath(sitedir, line)
            if not dircase in known_paths and os.path.exists(dir):
                sys.path.append(dir)
                known_paths.add(dircase)
        except Exception as err:
            print >>sys.stderr, "Error processing line {:d} of {}:\n".format(
                n+1, fullname)
            for record in traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()):
                for line in record.splitlines():
                    print >>sys.stderr, '  '+line
            print >>sys.stderr, "\nRemainder of file ignored"
            break
if reset:
    known_paths = None
return known_paths
```

<... skipped ...>

```
def addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths=None):
        """Add 'sitedir' argument to sys.path if missing and handle .pth files in
        'sitedir'"""
        if known_paths is None:
            known_paths = _init_pathinfo()
            reset = 1
        else:
            reset = 0
        sitedir, sitedircase = makepath(sitedir)
        if not sitedircase in known_paths:
            sys.path.append(sitedir)        # Add path component
        try:
            names = os.listdir(sitedir)  # <-- Line 184, here it stops for a lot of times
        except os.error:
            return
        dotpth = os.extsep + "pth"
        names = [name for name in names if name.endswith(dotpth)]
        for name in sorted(names):
            addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
        if reset:
            known_paths = None
        return known_paths
```

Also, the same thing with line 18 of `genericpath.py`:

```
def exists(path):
    """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
    try:
        os.stat(path)  #  <-- Line 18, breaks here very many times
    except os.error:
        return False
    return True
```

All this makes every debugging session very sloooow. How can I mask out these places so they don't stop execution any more?
I use Python 2.7.10 and Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 7 x64.

Comment: That sounds like you have some kind of setting set to break on file I/O.

Comment: Maybe, but I didn't set them. It's something from the default settings. Clearing out all breakpoints helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the **Debug** item in the menu, then select the **Delete All Breakpoints** option. The keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+F9** will accomplish the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps :)